# Fortify SCA 4.21's add-in not getting detected by VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fortify

When installing Fortify SCA 4.21, I can't seem to have it integrate with Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5).  I tried with installing the VS2013 Scan and  Remidiation plugin separately, and with the "VS2013 Plugin complete".  But it doesn't seem to get picked up by VS2013.

Does anyone know if and where the .addin file is created?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it.

The SCA installer puts the *.addin and a few *.reg registry files in the `%appdata%\local\fortify-installer\registry` folder.  Installing thekeys/values in the package2013.reg did the job.

Comment: Good job. VS2013 is no longer supported. I argued with the product manager about this, because the need to scan older applications was not going to go away.